# Javascript/Jquery: Number nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested list:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">first</li>
  <li id="2">second</li>
  <ul>
    <li id="2-1">second nested first element</li>
    <li id="2-2">second nested secondelement</li>
    <li id="2-3">second nested thirdelement</li>
        <ul>
          <li id="2-3-1">Other</li>
        </ul>

  </ul>
  <li id="3"i>third</li>
  <li id="4">fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Each element has an id that indicates the position within the list. How do I generate it automatically?
Thank you.

UPDATE:
html is generated by Apache velocity without ID. I'm trying to create a method for updating the id if you move elements with jquery sortable. The structure of the id must be "1" for the first item "1-1" for the first element of the first "li". I tried using index () but I can't generate the id in the form that I need

Comment: how and from what do you want to generate it? what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: The html is generated by Apache velocity without ID. I'm trying to create a method for updating the id if you move elements with jquery sortable. The structure of the id but must be "1" for the first item "1-1" for the first element of the first "li". I tried using index () but I can't generate the id in the form that I need (ex: "1-1 for first subitem of first item in the menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you exactly want to do here, but here's an example of generating dynamic li's with dynamic id's:

HTML:

```
<ul id="autoGenerated">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 3 ;i++){
    $("#autoGenerated").append("<li id=2-" + i + ">Testing " + i + "</li>")
}


$('#autoGenerated li').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
 })
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a35L8505/)**.

Comment: The html is generated by Apache velocity without ID. I'm trying to create a method for updating the id if you move elements with jquery sortable. The structure of the id but must be "1" for the first item "1-1" for the first element of the first "li". I tried using index () but I can't generate the id in the form that I need (ex: "1-1 for first subitem of first item in the menu)